# IntegerField not validating on empty string

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

I found that IntegerField does not validate when empty. To reproduce, copy the following block:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import IntegerField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False

class DemoForm(FlaskForm):
    demofield = IntegerField('demofield')

@app.route('/', methods=("GET","POST"))
def index():
    form = DemoForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return ("The form validated!")
    return render_template_string("<!DOCTYPE HTML> This is my form! <form method=\"post\">{% for field in form %}{{field}}{% endfor %}<input type=\"submit\">", form=form)

app.run(debug=True)
```

and save it in its own directory as app.py. Then open a terminal, cd to the directory, and run the following:

```
virtualenv flask
source flask/bin/activate
pip install flask flask-wtf
export FLASK_APP=app.py
python3 app.py
```

Connect to localhost:5000 in a web browser. Typing an integer into the form field and submitting will display "The form validated!" Typing something that is not an integer into the field, **or leaving the field blank**, and submitting just reloads the page. This does make some sense, since "" cannot be coerced into an integer.

I want to let my IntegerField be empty. I think the solution is to subclass IntegerField and [override pre_validate() or post_validate()](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.validate). I have:

```
class OptionalIntegerField(IntegerField):
    def post_validate(self, form, validation_stopped):
        print("post_validate is being called")
        if (self.data in (None, "")):
            return True
```

My question is:

- is subclassing and overriding the correct solution?
- if so, do I override pre_validate(), post_validate(), or both, and how? Do I need to `return True` inside them?

Comment: I will probably just make a custom validator for TextField instead.

Answer (score 7):

The `Optional` validator allows empty entries on form fields.

```
>>> from webob.multidict import MultiDict

>>> class F(Form):
...     foo = IntegerField(validators=[validators.Optional()])

>>> f = F(formdata=MultiDict(foo=1))
>>> f.validate()
True
>>> f = F(formdata=MultiDict(foo=''))
>>> f.validate()
True
>>> f = F(formdata=MultiDict(foo='a'))
>>> f.validate()
False
```

From the [docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#wtforms.validators.Optional):

> class wtforms.validators.Optional(strip_whitespace=True)
>
> Allows empty input and stops the validation chain from continuing.
>
> If input is empty, also removes prior errors (such as processing errors) from the field.

Answer (score 3):

This'll do it...

```
score = IntegerField('Score', validators=[Optional(strip_whitespace=True)])
```